# How to get date+interval?

Tags: org-mode, calendar

I have a deadline that is 12/12/2019+15d+1m. How would I get it in Emacs? This should be straightforward but have not found it. [The right answer](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/dateadded.html?m1=12&d1=12&y1=2019&type=add&ay=&am=1&aw=&ad=15&rec=) is 01/27.

UPDATE:

The question is *not* about combining two dates shifts. I'm fine with an answer to:

> Could you please show me the exact steps to get get 12/12/2019+15d,
>   and then 12/27/2019+1m?

[image]

Comment: What is the exact time, please, of 12/12/2019 in this example -- is it 12:00 a.m. or something other?  And, are you already aware of the functions that turn date/time/days into seconds since AD and visa/versa?

Comment: How would I know? If I click on it, it just opens the agenda for that date (like `open-at-point`, I think): 

Thursday   12 December 2019

Comment: I could not get the date parser in Org mode to accept two specs (`+1m` and `+15d` work separately, but not together), but it seems like a reasonable request and I imagine a fairly simple change in the code. You might want to do an RFE on the [Org mode mailing list](https://orgmode.org/community.html).

Comment: Could you please show me the exact steps to get each to work separately? IOTW, how do I get 12/12/2019+15d, and then 12/27/2019+1m?

Comment: Why isn't this question getting an answer?

Comment: Because nobody saw your comment: if I comment, you get to see the comment because you "own" the question. But if you want me to see the comment, you have to address your comment to me, using the `@NickD` construct. I only saw this because you posted it as a new question, linking back to this question.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @nickD.

Comment: See, I saw this comment :-)