# How to get date+interval? (revisited)

Tags: org-mode, calendar

I have a deadline that is some date *in the past*(such as 12/26/2019) + interval (e.g. 15d). How would I get it in Emacs? In [a previous post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/54621/how-to-get-dateinterval) under the same title I posted *an example* with interval = the sum of the two subintervals (15d+1m). Someone answered that would have to be a feature request, but was able to do it with only one interval. Actually, that is all I need, but still don't know how to do it. Would someone be so kind as to give a step by step instruction to do it?

Bottom line: how to get '12/26/2019+15d'?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a timestamp of `2019-12-12`, you can specify `++15d` (note the double plus) to move forward to `2019-12-27`, then you can specify `++1m` to move forward to `2020-01-27`. See the section of the manual entitled [The date/time prompt](https://orgmode.org/manual/The-date_002ftime-prompt.html#The-date_002ftime-prompt):

> With a single plus or minus, the date is always relative to today. With a double plus or minus, it is relative to the default date.

EDIT: Here's a more detailed workflow. The simplest method I know to do what you want is to use the date/time prompt and select your initial date from the calendar: e.g. for a SCHEDULE: date, say `C-c C-s` and click on 2019-12-12. That makes 2019-12-12 the default date, so you can say `C-c C-s` again and type `++15d` at the date/time prompt: that gets you to 2019-12-27 which is now the new default date. So you can do `C-c C-s` one more time and say `++1m` at the prompt to get you to 2020-01-27. Does that help?

Note that with `C-c .`, every time you modify the date, the cursor ends up *after* the date, so if you do it again, you end up with a date range. Just move the cursor back *into* the date before repeating it and you will not get a second date.

Comment: I can do it like this: `C-c .` Dp `S-<` as many times as needed to get to `12-26`. Then `RET`. Then `C-c . ++15d RET`, and I end up with two timestamps, one for `12-26`, another for `01/10`. I just need the second. It works, but is there a less cumbersome way?

Comment: Edited the answer with a more detailed workflow.

Comment: Edited again to point out why `C-c .` gives you a second date.